# <frozen importlib._bootstrap> error in python django

Tags: python, django

My name of the project is Proctor and i have shifted this project from my computer to laptop due to which I am facing errors. 
I have tried almost everything to solve this error but none worked for me.

1. Installed all missing modules
2. Executed all python manage.py (makemigrations/migrate) commands
3. Checked my installed apps. (nothing is missing)
   The models are migrated in the database. Now just python manage.py runserver has errors.
   *My python version is 3.10.7*

**Error:**

```
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
   return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "D:\1.Coding Softwares\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Desktop\Anish\Python Project\Online-Proctor-System\proctor\proctor\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 31, in get_handler        
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 78, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Dalvi\Envs\proctor\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'proctor.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

**TREE**

```
├───adminsite (app)
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───logreg (app)
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───proctor (project)
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───css
│   │   ├───adminsite
│   │   ├───login
│   │   └───usersite
│   ├───images
│   │   └───adminsite
│   └───js
│       ├───adminsite
│       └───usersite
├───static_root
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───css
│   │   ├───adminsite
│   │   ├───login
│   │   └───usersite
│   ├───images
│   │   └───adminsite
│   ├───js
│   │   ├───adminsite
│   │   └───usersite
│   └───static_root
│       ├───admin
│       │   ├───css
│       │   │   └───vendor
│       │   │       └───select2
│       │   ├───fonts
│       │   ├───img
│       │   │   └───gis
│       │   └───js
│       │       ├───admin
│       │       └───vendor
│       │           ├───jquery
│       │           ├───select2
│       │           │   └───i18n
│       │           └───xregexp
│       ├───css
│       │   ├───adminsite
│       │   ├───login
│       │   └───usersite
│       ├───images
│       │   └───adminsite
│       └───js
│           ├───adminsite
│           └───usersite
├───templates
│   ├───adminsite
│   ├───logreg
│   └───usersite
└───usersite (app)
    ├───migrations
    │   └───__pycache__
    └───__pycache__
```

**settings.py of project (proctor)**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import proctor

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-!2eg$jgi04pesan7_)@^((#o)fq($9namjy&gii=mi0s@ko-+n'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # logreg app
    'logreg.apps.LogregConfig',

    # crispy forms
    'crispy_forms',
   'adminsite.apps.AdminsiteConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'usersite',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_auto_logout.middleware.auto_logout',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proctor.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/usersite'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/logreg'),os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/adminsite')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proctor.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'proctor',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'root',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
   
]

STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_root")
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')



DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

#AUTO_LOGOUT = {'IDLE_TIME': 200}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

**wsgi.py of project (proctor)**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proctor.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Could you add the tree files and directories of your project ? And your wsgi.py file ?

Comment: sure. I am sorry about this as i was having no idea about the required stuff of error. i will do it

Comment: Where is your `wsgi.py` file located ?

Comment: @totor its in proctor folder

Comment: have you run `python manage.py check`?     Near top of `settings.py` you  have `import proctor`.... I don't see why that should hurt anything but you aren't using it, try removing that.l

Comment: @LevinMagruder yes after running `python manage.py check` i got no issues and even after removing `import proctor` i am getting same errors <frozen importlib> one

Comment: if you rename `wsgi.py` to `xxxx.py`, and then `runserver`, of course it will fail but does it still fail with same message... want to verify if the problem is that it's not finding wsgi.py at all, or if something in wsgi.py is causing an error with no diagnostic... neither seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed a lower version of Python i.e. from 3.10 to 3.7 and then installed all the missing modules

```
pip install pymysql
python -m pip install Pillow
pip install cryptography
pip install django_auto_logout
pip install requests_html
```